# Want to understand why PriorityQueue.addAll method is not considering comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue, min-heap

I have the below code written to add a collection of Integers to the Priority Queue. I am getting confused on the out put

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] pipes = {4, 3, 2, 6 };
    PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1-o2;
        }
    });
    minHeap.addAll(IntStream.of(pipes).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println(minHeap);
}
```

I expect the output as  `[2, 3, 4, 6]` but it is printed as `[2, 4, 3, 6]`. Could someone please explain why 3 is not printed before 4?? Am i doing something wrong with addAll method??

Comment: A PriorityQueue is not a sorted list. Elements are not expected to be in order.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have a follow up question. Even if i am creating a Queue with a comparator, still not a sorted list. If so, then can you please tell me the purpose of giving the comparator to the Queue?

Comment: ohh i think i am missing the basic point. PriorityQueue make sure that Smallest Element is maintained at the top of the Queue[in the case of Minheap with above comparator] and need not be the entire list sorted.